# Using HybridAuth in Laravel 5 Error Cannot declare class Hybrid_Auth

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement google login in laravel 5.3. I installed hybridauth using composer: `composer require hybridauth/hybridauth`

However, first i got the error:

> "Class Hybrid_Auth not found"

So I added a namespace `namespace Hybridauth;` to each class in Hybridauth (path in project: vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid), and included it in my controller using use Hybridauth\Hybrid_Auth;  But now i get the error:

> FatalErrorException in Auth.php line 16: "Cannot declare class
>   Hybridauth\Hybrid_Auth, because the name is already in use"

Even though I've searched the entire project and the class `Hybrid_Auth` is only declared once.

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Hybridauth\Hybrid_Auth;

    class AuthController extends Controller
    {
        public function googleLogin($auth=null)
        {
          if($auth == 'auth')
          {
              try
              {
                  Hybrid_Endpoint::process();
              }
              catch(Exception $e)
              {
                  return Redirect::to('googleAuth');
              }
              return;
          }
          $config = array(
          "base_url" => "localhost:8000/gauth",
          "providers" => array (
            "Google" => array (
              "enabled" => true,
              "keys"    => array ( "id" => "googleIdGoeshEre", "secret" => "googleSecretKeyGoeshEre" ),
              "scope"           => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile ". // optional
                                   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"   , // optional
              "access_type"     => "offline",   // optional
              "approval_prompt" => "force",     // optional
              "hd"              => "domain.com" // optional
        )));
          $oauth = new Hybrid_Auth($config);
          $provider = $oauth->authenticate("Google");
          $profile = $provider->getUserProfile();
          return var_dump($profile).'<br><a href="logout">Logout</a>';
    }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I added a namespace namespace Hybridauth; to each class in
>   Hybridauth (path in project:
>   vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid)

Editing file in `vendor` folder is not a good idea, because when you do `composer update` those files will get update, then you have to edit again.

I suggest you remove the namespace you added in the vendor folder. And add `use Hybrid_Auth;` in the Controller

Make sure you are including the hybrid auth. `require_once( "/path/to/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php");`